# Convert int array of byte to String in JAVA

Tags: java, string, byte

i have following problem:

i have array of 2 `int` - its char `ř` how can i convert this array to `string` or `char`?

real values in array are: `[-59, -103]`

`ř`->`[-59, -103]`->`ř`
Thank you.

EDIT:

```
    String specialChar = "ř";
    System.out.println(specialChar);
    byte[] tmp = specialChar.getBytes();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp)); //[-59, -103]
    int[] byteIntArray = new int[2];
    byteIntArray[0] = (int) tmp[0];
    byteIntArray[1] = (int) tmp[1];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteIntArray)); //[-59, -103]
    //now i want convert byteIntArray to string
```

Comment: Do you have an `int[]` or a `byte[]`?

Comment: @BrettOkken I edited post, look to real code example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that?

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[2];
byteArray[0] = (byte)byteIntArray[0];
byteArray[1] = (byte)byteIntArray[1];
String specialChar = new String(byteArray);
```

Note that `String.getBytes()` uses your local platform encoding to convert the string into a byte array. So the resulting byte array depends on your individual system settings.

If you want your byte array to be compatible to other systems, use a standard encoding like "UTF-8" instead:

```
byte[] tmp = specialChar.getBytes("UTF-8"); // String -> bytes
String s = new String(tmp, "UTF-8");        // bytes -> String
```